# JPopupMenu not showing text of JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

I'm trying to create a `JPopupMenu`, but for some reason, it doesn't show the text I've set on the `JMenuItems`. The menu itself works, there are menuitems in it and they are responsive, but the text is not showing. I'm creating the menu like this:

```
private void createPopupMenu() {
    this.popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();      
    this.addMouseListener(new PopupListener(this));
    JMenuItem addPlaceMenuItem = new JMenuItem(SketchPad.ADD_PLACE_POPUP_TEXT);
    addPlaceMenuItem.setAction(new PopupAction(ActionType.AddPlace));
    this.popupMenu.add(addPlaceMenuItem);
    JMenuItem addTransitionMenuItem = new JMenuItem(SketchPad.ADD_TRANSITION_POPUP_TEXT);
    addTransitionMenuItem.setAction(new PopupAction(ActionType.AddTransition));
    this.popupMenu.add(addTransitionMenuItem);      
}
```

In case it matters, here is the `PopupListener`:

```
class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {

    SketchPad pad;

    public PopupListener(SketchPad pad)
    {
        this.pad = pad;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        {
            this.pad.getController().deselectAllNodes();
        }
        else
        {
            maybeShowPopup(e);
        }
    }

    private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {               
            pad.popupPosition = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            pad.popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Consider using JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu instead of using a MouseListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but for some reason, it doesn't show the text I've set on the JMenuItems.

```
addPlaceMenuItem.setAction(new PopupAction(ActionType.AddPlace));
```

The `setAction(...)` method reset the properties of the menu item with the properties of the Action. So you need to make sure you set the `NAME` property of the `Action` to set the text of the menu item.

So in your case it looks like the value of the NAME property should be:

```
SketchPad.ADD_PLACE_POPUP_TEXT
```

Or the other approach is to reset the text of the menu item after you set the Action

```
JMenuItem addPlaceMenuItem = new JMenuItem( new PopupAction(ActionType.AddPlace) );
addPlaceMenuItem.setText(SketchPad.ADD_PLACE_POPUP_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 2):

The effect is platform specific. In particular, "In Microsoft Windows, the user by convention brings up a popup menu by [*releasing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) the right mouse button while the cursor is over a component that is popup-enabled." Your implementation of `mouseReleased()` precludes even checking `isPopupTrigger()`. Instead, handle the selection *and* check the trigger. A similar approach is shown in [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) in order to handle multiple selection and a context menu.